In Qt, can I use parameter references（&） as parameters of signal slot functions?
I need to pass a large amount of data from the worker thread to the main thread. I tried to use the signal slot method to pass the variable reference, but I am not sure whether it will cause program exceptions due to the scope of the variable, because the parameter in the signal function is a local variable. Some people told me that it is possible, but some people told me that it is not possible. Please help me
Following is my code
// GUI thread
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_thread = new QThread(this);

    m_socket = new MySocket();
    connect(m_socket,&MySocket::sendData,this,&Widget::onSendData);
    m_socket->moveToThread(m_thread);

    m_thread->start();
}

void Widget::onSendData(QByteArray &data)
{
    // to do something
}

// work thread

void MySocket::onReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray datagram;
    datagram.resize(m_socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    QHostAddress peerAddr;
    quint16 peerPort;
    m_socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &peerAddr, &peerPort);

    emit sendData(datagram);
}

Is the code correct? Will the variable “datagram” go out of scope?

Just out of interest, why does onSendData accept a non-const reference?  See also "stack object Qt signal and parameter as reference".

Thanks for the suggestion. From the link you gave, it can be concluded that the types registered with the meta-object system can be passed by reference
